# How to do a large mongo import?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo and will explain how I am doing my import shortly. I am looking for a way to cut the time down because right now it hardly manages to import 500 000 records in 12 hours.

What I have is:

- A table called "carsA" and "carsB"
- Both these tables contain a field "car_id"
- I want to merge these two tables into a single table called "cars"

So what I do is:

1. Get the first 5000 rows from "carsA" and import it into the new Database
2. Get the next 5000 rows from "carsA" and import it into the new Database
3. Do this until it finishes

This already takes extremely long, but the next part has an additional call. Because the two tables might have the same car_id,s when I do the import for carsB, I first have to check if that car_id has not already been imported.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this more effectively. Mongo is lightning fast with queries but importing seems to be a pain, at least in this way.

Is there a better way?

Comment: In MySql you can do `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (SELECT * FROM carsA, carsB GROUP BY car_id)`. Maybe something is in MongoDb?

Comment: Or maybe first insert everything from `carsB`, than get all `car_id` and exclude it from `carsA` - import what's left.

Comment: [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) is pretty fast in my experience because it uses a multithreaded process to parallelize your import. You can pipe the results from your database query via stdin to it. Also, it continues by default when there is a duplicate key.

Comment: At least tell how you import and where. If it is self-hosted, try to upload the files to the server and import from the local files.

Comment: Will the new cars table be in the same database/server where carsA and carsB tables currently are??